# transfer files from one webserver to another

Tags: php, apache, ftp, cpanel, ftps

I want to transfer files from a webserver to another approx 1GB, I have access to both server ftp and ftps.

How can I do it with fast way.. I don't want to download files to my computer and then upload to new server.

Thanks

Comment: If you have SSH access, use WGET

Comment: I have cpanel access, how can i enable ssh?

Comment: use rsync via the exec command and an ignore user interupt flag in a php script that will do it.  make sure you delete the file afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Given that SSH is not available to all offers, and to all customers, I recommend using net2ftp, which allows copying/moving files from one FTP server to another.

Connect to your FTP account (source) here : http://www.net2ftp.com. Once you're in there, select the files you want to copy/move, and choose the appropriate option in the top menu. You'll have the possibility to specify another FTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Now, I think it is easy. adding two host's ftp account to a multi-cloud management application called MultCloud(https://www.multcloud.com), then you can transfer files in one interface, beacuse MultCloud is a web-based application and 100% free.

Answer (score 0):

use the php ftp functions. Set `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` and `ignore_user_abort(1)`

then

```
$File = "PathToFile";

$Ftp = ftp_connect("IP of the othe server that will receive the file");

ftp_login($Ftp,"ftpuser","ftppassword");

ftp_pasv($Ftp,true); // Join pasv which is always better

ftp_put($Ftp,"Path in the remote server",$File,FTP_BINARY); 

ftp_close($Ftp);
```

Always use FTP_BINARY when sending binary files

and of course fire the php script, via web browser or cron

Edit: Forgot ftp_login()